# Typings for an object where keys and values are the same

Tags: typescript, types

Is there a way in typescript to express the typings of a function that takes in a list of strings, and creates an object where each key's value is the key itself:

```js
const createActionTypes = (types: string[]) => {
  return types.reduce((typesMap, type) => {
    typesMap[type] = type
    return typesMap
  }, {})
}
```

```js
// Input
createActionTypes(['a', 'b'])

// Output
{ a: 'a', b: 'b' }
```

Here's what I've tried, without luck:

```js
const createActionTypes = <T extends readonly string[], U extends T[number]>(
  types: T
): { [key in U]: U } => {
  return types.reduce((typesMap, type) => {
    typesMap[type] = type
    return typesMap
  }, {})
}

const x = createActionTypes(['a', 'b'] as const)
// Typings for x get resolved to: 
{
  a: "a" | "b";
  b: "a" | "b";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are *really* close. You need to specify that the value is same type as `key` and not the whole set `"a"|"b"` which is `U`.

[TS Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/zwO3yw)

```ts
const createActionTypes = <T extends readonly string[], U extends T[number]>(
  types: T
): { [key in U]: key } => {
  return types.reduce((typesMap, type) => {
    typesMap[type] = type
    return typesMap
  }, {} as any)
}

const x = createActionTypes(['a', 'b'] as const)
```

<sub>Also, just for clarity, I would avoid using reserved words like `type` as a variable or function parameter. It required me to look twice to ensure `type` is not type, but a value.</sub>