# How to write type for the key when creating an object?

Tags: typescript

I want to create an object with key and typing that with function. But I have an error.

I have found the [alike answer but for array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66066252/7879581). Is it possible to have the same only for one key *without assertion*?

[Link to Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAZgrgdgxgLgSwPZQAQwE4FMCGcsA8AKqlgB75QAmAzqjXBglAOYB8AFEzAFypEBKPgG8A2gGssAT1TN%20AXT4MmrAL6phoVNtQB6XfykAHLKgDkw1KLJLGzFovp3WAblSqzsulCRxUOGhoEFigcACMAG1M4JFQ4Y1MLK0kZOSJHZXs3VS0dbDgIDDRLUW5HMwA3HAiILDNVN1AckCA)

```js
function create<T extends string>(ric: T): {[key in T]: string} {
    // Type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ [key in T]: string; }
    return { [ric]: 'value'}; 
}
```

The workaround:

```js
return { [ric]: 'value'} as {[key in T]: string};
```

Comment: Side note: They're [*type assertions*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions), not casting, not that it usually matters.

Comment: (Looks like the short answer is: you need the assertion.)